# Can't upgrade cocoapods from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

> $ gem update cocoapods
>
> Updating installed gems
>
> Nothing to update
>
> $ pod --version
>
> 1.0.0

==========================================

> $ gem install cocoapods
>
> Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
>
> Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
>
> Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 3 seconds
>
> 1 gem installed
>
> $ pod --version
>
> 1.0.0

How can I upgrade to 1.0.1?

=======

I think the problem is I installed two cocoapods via `sudo gem install cocoapods` and `gem install cocoapods`
So I remove all of them and install again, the version is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade cocoapods by run following cmd:

- upgrade to the latest version by running `gem update cocoapods`
- upgrade to spec version by running `gem install cocoapods -v 1.0.1`